# Upgrade symfony from skeleton to website-skeleton

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I've just been experimenting with Symfony 4, and started out with a console app, so ran:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project
```

I now realise that was a mistake, and instead want the website skeleton

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

What's the simplest way to upgrade my existing project to have everything that comes in website-skeleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've just been experimenting, the simplest way would be to create a new project with `symfony/website-skeleton` and eventually integrate into it the code you developped and want to keep.

`symfony/website-skeleton` is not an upgrade, it just installs more dependencies by default for users who don't want to install them manually.
So if you really want to keep the existing project, you could add the missing dependencies yourself with composer.

You can find a list of the dependencies [here](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/website-skeleton).